# ¿Es posible guardar en MySQL, en un campo tipo Blob, una imagen que está en internet?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy realizando una sistema web con login, en el que los usuarios pueden actualizar su foto de perfil si lo desean, pero cuando se crea el perfil de un usuario, me gustaría que en el campo de la imagen (del tipo Blob en BD), se guarde una silueta y posteriormente el cliente la cambia si desea. ¿Me podrán ayudar? Ya la actualización de la foto la tengo lista, pero cuando no se ha hecho, en el div que tengo de la imagen, sale blanco.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento: lee [ask].

Comment: No he intentado nada sobre lo que pregunto, porque no sé cómo hacerlo, y debido a que no he encontrado información en internet sobre cómo hacerlo, accedí a este medio para ver quién me puede responder acerca de: si es posible y cómo se podría hacer.

Comment: La mejor opción es que el usuario suba la imagen desde un campo tipo `file`. Si quieres que se copie desde una URL vas a tener que usar la librería [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php).

Comment: Claro, así lo hice, ya lo tengo funcionando, el usuario puede actualizar la imagen, pero lo que quiero es que recién creada la cuenta, como éste no tiene una foto definida, provisionalmente salga una silueta y no un espacio en blanco del div.

Comment: Hay dos problemas con respecto a tu pregunta: 1. No es clara. ¿Desde dónde tomará el usuario la imagen, desde un archivo local, desde una URL o la puede tomar de una parte o de otra indistintamente? Habiendo definido eso, surge el otro problema: 2. Hay mil formas de procesar imágenes/archivos en PHP, debes investigar tú, decidirte por una herramienta o modo de hacerlo e intentar un código. Si te quedas bloqueado en ese código entonces te ayudaremos. Lamentablemente, no podemos elegir una herramienta por ti, mucho menos sin explicar con claridad el problema.

Comment: Porque insisten en guardar imagenes en la db, cuando el filesystem es un gran lugar para guardarlas? fijate que si guardaras solo la ruta, podrias tener ya la silueta y poner la ruta a esa silueta por defecto...

Comment: Si es posible pero no es buena practica. Lo suyo seria convertir el blob a base64 y guardarlo (en el backend) a disco como jpg,png o lo que sea y colocar en la db una ruta a dicha imagen ya sea httplocalhost o httpproduccio

Comment: mira este enlace amigo a ver si te sirve : https://programacion.net/articulo/almacenar_y_recuperar_una_imagen_de_una_base_de_datos_mysql_mediante_php_1861

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: @gbianchi Soy nuevo en programación. De igual forma, gracias por tu aporte.

Comment: @A.Cedano 1: El usuario solo creará su cuenta. El proceso de actualizar la foto lo tengo listo; creo que no fui confuso cuando dije que el #Actualizar Foto ya está listo, pero cuando el usuario crea su cuenta, el campo donde va la foto queda vacío, y en el contenedor donde la muestro, queda en blanco, lógicamente. Solo quiero que ese campo (de tipo blob), almacene una foto de una silueta mientras el usuario decide poner una foto suya, repito, la función de "actualizar foto" está lista. Sobre lo segundo, no puedo decirle nada, he hecho lo que he podido, tengo mínima experiencia. Gracias, igual.